# Import PNG texture to memory but not framebuffer- using C++ and OpenGL

Tags: c++, memory, opengl, png, textures

I am investigating a possible method of collision detection for a simple game I am developing but I am now stuck.

I am trying to load a texture into memory but not into the frame buffer and read pixels (specifically, the colour) from it using coordinates...I can read the buffer contents easily and get the color of pixels at coordinates but I cannot work out how to do this on a texture, is it even possible?

Any help/guidance/what to research or possible functions would be much appreciated.

Note: I am using OpenGL 2.0

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL is not a image manipulation, nor image access library. It's a drawing API and as such it should be treated. Reading back (whole) textures is possible with OpenGL (though not very performant). On OpenGL-ES there's no direct way to read texture data.

You already have the whole texture image in a regular buffer? Good, because that's what you want to operate on anyway. Reading back single pixels for their color is just stupid, because it clogs up the CPU with function call overhead.

Comment: I appreciate what you're saying but I wasn't stating to do it only in OpenGL, I was saying I am using OpenGL with C++ to load in PNGs as textures - I don't care how I read the textures, be it in C++ or OpenGL, I was asking for the best method but thanks for your advice, I will bare that in mind and try and think of other solutions.

Comment: @trystan: OpenGL doesn't deal with loading images from files, so whatever method you're using to load a PNG into a texture, it should also give you the buffer with the texture data as it is also used to upload the data to OpenGL. I suggest you take the data from there.

Comment: @trystan Well, like the datenwolf said, the best method is to not use OpenGL for this. Just take the pixel values from the CPU memory buffer you already have (since you loaded the image from a file into CPU memory, didn't you?).

Comment: @trystan: Try LodePNG for PNG loading. LodePNG works well and is small and easy to use. http://lodev.org/lodepng/

Answer (score 0):

decode png to regular buffer.
create texture by glGenTextures;
bind texture by glBindTexture;
load image to texture by glTexImage2D.

Comment: I understand that but how do I go about reading pixels from a texture? glReadPixels only reads pixels from the framebuffer. Thanks

Comment: @trystan: Why do you need to read pixels from the texture? You gave the texture its data; unless you render to that texture later, it will have the same pixels you gave it. So just keep the buffer around after you create the texture if you need it on the CPU.

Comment: I have multiple textures rendered to the framebuffer so reading from the framebuffer is no good, I need to read from a specific texture/image as this will be used as a reference for collision detection if that clarifies anything?